# Is it possible to hardcode constructor arguments?

Tags: java

Before I was using;

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
   try 
   {
       ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
   }
}
```

and then having parameter argument

```
-ORBInitialPort 1050
```

I now want to remove the main section of the code and have the class being created inside another class, so is it possible to hardcode these arguments? Or do i have to pass the data from the new class into the class that needs it?

Comment: mmh maybe you need to rephrase a bit, not sure what you're asking here...

Comment: maybe you could create a wrapper class for that?

Comment: You can have global values passed with `-Dfoo=bar` to your program then you just need to get the value with `System.getProperty("foo")` if this is what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you mean the static initializer method (for CORBA). You can do

```
String[] newArgs = {"-ORBInitialPort", "1050"}; 
ORB orb = ORB.init(newArgs, null);
```